# Webhook Integration using api gateway and lambda function(python)

Tags: aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-api-gateway, webhooks, python-3.11

I am working on poc to setup provider webhook event notifications data integration with aws api gateway and lambda function (python ) and load payload flattened data into snowflake.
PLEASE HELP !!

Working on architecture and poc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.